# Unable to read nested arrays with the same names

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working with a large set of nested arrays in PHP. The data originally started as a JSON data object that was converted with `json_decode true`. I've been able to navigate the resulting nested array without too much issue up till now. I've run into the following problem.

```
Scores
    Team1
        Info1
        Info2
            Element1
            Element2
        **Info3**
            Element1
                Item1
                Item2
            Element2
                Item1
                Item2
        **Info3**
            Element1
                Item1
                Item2
            Element2
                Item1
                Item2
```

The problem is that `Info3` are two distinct arrays with their own collections of data that I need to extract, but they have the same exact name. Running something like:

`echo $Scores['Team1']['Info3'][0]['Item1']`

Works to a degree; but it only captures the items of the elements of the *last* `Info3` instance. `Info3` instances further up the chain are ignored. I've also tried specifying the instance of the array I want specifically, like so:

`$echo $Scores['Team1'][3]['Element1']['Item1']`

Which is very similar to the above but for some reason doesn't work. It's as if the `Element` arrays are keyed, but the `Info` arrays are not. I've also tried a `foreach` loop through `Team1` and taking action only if the value was equal to `Info3`, but again no joy. To further complicate things, the number of `Info3` arrays is itself variable, number 0-5, so my capture has to be similarly dynamic.

Edit: Adding a JSON snippet, as requested.

```
"scores": {
                    "team1": {
                        "info1": 0,
                        "info2": [
                            {
                                "element1": 1,
                                "element2": 144568658
                            },
                            {
                                "element1": 2,
                                "element2": 132020087
                            }
                        ]
                        ,
                        "info3": [
                            {
                                "item1": 5462,
                                "item2": 1
                            }
                        ]
                        ,
                        "info3": [
                            {
                                "item1": 5608,
                                "item2": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "item1": 5611,
                                "item2": 1
                            }
                        ]
                        ,
                        "info3": [
                            {
                                "item1": 5127,
                                "item2": 1
                            }
                        ]

                    },
                    "team2": { etc...
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone who took time to answer. Seems the problem with not with my coding attempts but with the JSON source being malformed.

Comment: can you provide your json? Then we might have an easier time helping you

Comment: Also, it is not very clear what you are actually trying to do as you navigate the data. This is likely to affect the decision of the best way to navigate it.

Comment: This is a situation that's normal and natural for xml, but not for json...

Comment: You are aware that a PHP array can't have two keys the same?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: The echo is basically just for testing. Ultimately I will need to read the data into a database for later use.

Comment: Seems to me like a key conflict - it would really be helpful to see the source json file. As Paul Kienitz said, this is common for XML, but in JSON such a conflict is not possible either AFAIK.

Comment: @MarkBaker: This is the way the data arrives from the API and it's what I have to work with.

Comment: I think this would break javascript as well..... the answer is that you'll have to write your own parser from scratch to deal with malformed json; or get your API guys to return valid json

Comment: When I `json_decode` that, I only get the last `info3` element, which makes sense. I was kind of surprised it actually worked without error.

Comment: If I were to decode this into an object instead of an array I suppose the problem would still exist, since the issue with the JSON source encoding to begin with?

Comment: Yes, it would have the same problem.

Comment: A possible work-around may be that you could use file_get_contents() to retrieve it as a string. Then loop through all instances of info3 and replace them with a unique identifier such as "info3-n" (where n is the loop counter). From there use json_decode to parse it as an array

Comment: @Jujunol: This is an interesting suggestion. We're going to try working with the JSON output as a string to clean it up. I'll update with what we come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the comment from Jujunol we came up with this workaround for the bad JSON data:

```
$info3Count = substr_count($jsonString, '"info3": [');
$c = 1;
while ($c <= $info3Count) {
    $pos = strpos($jsonString, '"info3": [');
    $jsonString = substr_replace($jsonString, '"info3-'.$c.'": [', $pos,
        strlen('"info3": ['));
    $c++;
}
```

Basically, we imported the JSON as raw text, hunted through it for `info3` instances and appended a `-n` to the end of it where `n` was a simple counter. This rendered each instance of `info3` unique enough for a successful `json_decode`.